# PyDev and pygame: Undefined Variable From Import Errors

Tags: python, pygame, pydev

I am making a game using pygame and PyDev. Whenever I reference any member of the pygame module (i. e. `pygame.init`), PyDev gives an "undefined variable from import" error, even though the code itself is perfectly fine. Members of submodules don't give this error message, and using `from pygame.locals import *` gives "undefined variable" errors.

<strike>I have tried adding pygame as a forced builtin, to no avail.</strike> I tried it again and it worked. I'm not sure what had happened before.

Code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init() <== Error raised here
```

Comment: can u provide your code..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding `pygame` to the `Forced Builtins`?

You can find more information on how to do that and why this may fix your issue at: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins